# Why does my webcam mess up like this?

Tags: video, skype, webcam

Most of the time (but not always) when I am in a video call, the video has two sorts of overlay images, like in the examples below (cropped from original whole program window).

One overlay is a green grid, and another consists of two off-color shadows of the original video, offset vertically. 
Sometimes this effect happens to my own video, and sometimes to what I receive. Never both at once, and sometimes on neither.

me: [image]
other end: [image]

I use **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** with a [Logitech C905](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RZNI4S) webcam (2MP, autofocus, etc.) and Skype 4.3.0.37, the newest version for Linux. My counterpart in this screenshot uses the same OS, same Skype version, same webcam - but he doesn't see this effect at all.

`lsusb` seems to detect the webcam properly. I don't see anything wrong in the Skype settings, and the tiny video preview is okay:
[image]

I have recently reinstalled **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** from scratch but this issue remains even after that. I've tried to test with Google Hangouts, and that seems okay. I've tried `cheese` too and that also worked. But the answer can't be "use a different chat app" because the people I Skype with only have Skype, and they're mostly grandpa generation - I don't want to burden *them* with *my* video problem.

--> What's causing this, and **how can I fix this?**
I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is "you can't, Skype for Linux is deprecated and broken" but I hope there might be a chance.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with any other software that uses your webcam?

Comment: @Tobias as I mentioned, I could not replicate it in Hangouts or Cheese, and not even in the Skype settings! And it doesn't even happen in _every_ Skype video call - and when it does, sometimes it's in my thumbnail, sometimes in the received image. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Then it sounds very much like it's a Skype bug of some sort. I don't think anyone other than the Skype team will be able to help. If it was the hardware, or the underlying library that Skype uses, it should be replicable at least in the Skype settings window.

Comment: I'm going to try 16.04.b2 and see if that has any effect.